# Why is Harry the jealous one in the following paragraph, and why is 幸せな時間はなかった not a negation?

Tags: meaning

This paragraph comes from the second *Harry Potter* book.

[image]

I am not yet at a stage where I can read books comfortably, and I have trouble understanding this paragraph.

The English original goes as follows:

> The end of the summer vacation came too quickly for Harry’s liking. He
> was looking forward to getting back to Hogwarts, but his month at the
> Burrow had been the happiest of his life. It was difficult not to feel jealous of
> Ron when he thought of the Dursleys and the sort of welcome he could expect
> next time he turned up on Privet Drive.

To my mind, in the Japanese translation Harry has *not* had a pleasant time at the Weasleys. To that same mind it is also Ron that is jealous of Harry, and not the other way round. What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, 「（X）は（Y)が妬ましい」 is the typical way to say '[X] envies [Y]', because this is an adjective and not a verb - you can see this in other places too such as with 好き, 嫌い, and うらやましい.

Second, you are not taking the whole clause into account with 幸せな時間はなかった。

> 「隠れ穴」での一ヵ月**ほど**、幸せな時間はなかった。

> He [had] never had *such a happy time* as his month at the Burrow.

You could add これまで to the start to clear away ambiguity but it's far from necessary. ほど is used for certain comparisons.